# Removing html comments with javascript for loop produces error

Tags: javascript, html, comments

Hi I am having a beast of a time removing comments from html code (so innerHTML counting works in IE). I admit I am not the brightest bulb :) I do not have access to (knowledge of) jquery or the source as such to remove them. I am terrible with regex so I havent tried this

I tried the following code

```
<script>        
function clean(node)
        {
    for(var n = 0; n &lt; node.childNodes.length; n++)
      {
        var child = node.childNodes[n];
        if
        (
          child.nodeType === 8 ||
          (child.nodeType === 3 &amp;&amp; !/S/.test(child.nodeValue))
        )
        {
          node.removeChild(child);
          n--;
        }
        else if(child.nodeType === 1)
        {
          clean(child);
        }
      }
    }
</script>
```

But this is giving me error in all browsers:

```
SyntaxError: missing ) after for-loop control
for(var n = 0; n &lt; node.childNodes.length; n++)
```

Any ideas would be great. There are a bunch of jquery scripts on the page but I have no control over these and they do not have any errors that occur so I do not think this is related.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Hopefully you're not using HTML enitites in your javascript, and those are just typos ?

Comment: a correct `for` loop is like `for(var n = 0, len=node.childNodes.length; i<len; ++i) {... }` - that is what you are having an error on

Comment: oh yeah, and Matus points out `&amp;&amp;` can be just `&&`

Comment: @RobSedgwick - Are you saying there's something wrong with the current for loop if you replace the HTML entity with a < ?

Comment: @adeneo, no. -  just showing it in full ( the best variation of ) rather than saying replace `&lt;` with `<` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you remove the comments via Javascript, they will still be visible in View Source since it shows the source from *before* the Javascript ran.

If you don't want comments to be visible to the user, don't use HTML comments.  Use comments in a serverside language inside the server-side blocks.  Like:

```
<%
   //comment: printing variable x
   out.print(x);
%>
```

Comment: Bleh yeah to little sleep :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would start by replacing "&lt ;" with "<", and the same goes for your ampersands.